Azure Function deploy step is failing in pipeline
I set up a pipeline to deploy my Azure function app.  When it gets to the AzureFunctionApp@2 step it fails
Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'ServiceName'
##[error]Access Restrictions - Access to the "AzureWebJobsStorage" Storage Account resource is restricted. This can be due to firewall rules on the resource. Please check if you have configured firewall rules or a private endpoint and that they correctly allow access from the Function App. Relevant documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal

Exception encountered while connecting: Key based authentication is not permitted on this storage account.
NOTE: Function app is NOT VNet integrated.
##[error]Error: Networking validation for the Function app and Storage account has failed. Please review all error messages.

My config is simple.  My function app has a system managed identity that has a role of Storage Blob Data Owner on the storage account.  Key based authentication is disabled as a company standard setting.
I learned that Consumption app service plans don't support managed identity access to Azure Store files so I upgraded my app service plan from Consumption to Elastic. No difference in the error.
The networking is set to only allow Azure resources to access the storage.
What have I missed?

UPDATE
Based on my conversation with @amit_g I updated the network settings for the Function App.  I tried with an IP restriction and then opened it up to all traffic and the error persists.


Azure DevOps agents are not considered "Azure Services" and need to be whitelisted directly. Unfortunately there is no Service Tag that can be used and entire geography would need to be whitelisted. Other choices are to open up the SCM completely or whitelist the deployment agent's IP using a custom task.

@amit_g, are you saying to add the region IP addresses to the Firewall section in my screenshot?

The screenshot is for the storage account. The failure is for the function app deployment which is where the network restriction needs to be relaxed (only for SCM). Yes, it needs to be either completely open or whole region where the DevOps org is based needs to be whitelisted!! I am assuming you are using the Microsoft Hosted agents. Another option is to use self hosted agents but that has its own set of complications.

@amit_g I can't find where that is set in the function app.  I can't find anything similar under the Network settings.

Restrict access to an SCM site

Finally figured it out.  The AzureWebJobsStorage uses key access by default.  I disabled key access.  You have to update the name of the setting to be AzureWebJobsStorage_accountName and the value is just the storage account name.  This will allow the function app to use the Managed Identity to access the storage instead of the key.
Thanks to this blog for the answer and I swiped the screenshot from there. https://kumarashwinhubert.com/secure-your-azure-functions-use-managed-identity-for-azurewebjobsstorage.  Scoll down to "Edit the 'AzureWebJobsStorage' configuration"

